# angularjs http post is not working in file upload tag

Tags: http, angularjs, file-upload, http-post, multipartform-data

File uploading in `angularjs` is not working. I didn't find any requests send to backend in browser, in debugging mode I checked in both browser and backend:

```
<div>
    <input type="file" accept="text/plain" name="tandcproduct"
    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadTerms(this.files)" ng-required/>
</div>
```

js code:

```
 $scope.uploadTerms = function(files) {
    fd.append("file", files[0]);
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url: ctxPath+'fileupload/productconfig',
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            data: fd
            }).
            then(function(result) {
            alert(result);
            });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you go through some [tutorials](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) first you'll find the answer.

Comment: @Stewie, I have worked on many http post requests in past.. the same code will works outside of file upload method but its not working in it? got it?

Comment: Inline use of `onchange` attribute is deprecated some 10 years ago. Accessing your scope method with `angular.element(this).scope()` is utter abuse of all angular practices. Again, I advise going through the docs, tutorials, and docs for `ng-change` directive.

Comment: From the docs: "If the data property of the request configuration object contains an object, serialize it into JSON format."

Comment: ng-click="uploadTerms()" event is firing in the above context. but without of angular.element(this).scope().uploadTerms(this.files) is not working.in anyother methods post object is working